# Making memoir Chapter entries in ToC all-caps and Appendix entries regular case, without breaking hyperref

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents, memoir, etoolbox

I have a thesis style working, but around 10% of my code is a copy of memoir's `\def\@chapter` that lets me put all regular chapter entries in all caps, and keep appendix entries in regular case. This works, but I'd assume there was an easier way.

Ideally, I'd like to have my students keep using the `\chapter` command rather than define my own document division.

I've managed to find a split in the logic between chapters and appendices in memoir.cls -- chapters call the `\l@chapter` command, and appendices call the `\l@appendix` command:

```
\newcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{#1}{#2}{\cftchaptername}}

\newcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{#1}{#2}{\cftappendixname}}
```

I've tried adding an `\uppercase` to the first one as shown below, but doing this breaks hyperrefs -- the links are still present, but have a black border and don't link to the right place. Minimal example (comment out the `\renewcommand` for a ToC with proper links but wrong case, or leave it in for the right case and dead links):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{\uppercase{#1}}{#2}{\cftchaptername}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\appendix \appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with broken links]
[image: ToC with links intact]

---

EDIT (2011/02/23): I've had another idea to patch `\@chapter` instead of copying all its code and making the one change. But that's failing, too. I suspect it's either because I haven't escaped backslashes or other characters properly:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ifpatchable*{\@chapter}{\typeout{Chapter can be patched}}{\typeout{Chapter cannot be patched}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}{\protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtoc}}{\typeout{Succeeded}}{\typeout{Failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\appendix \appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which returns in the log

```
Chapter can be patched
Failed
```

SECOND EDIT (2011/02/23): working etoolbox patch is in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11892/hyperref-breaks-my-all-caps-toc-entries), but hyperref still interferes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What follows is only a partial solution because it typesets regular chapter entries in *small* caps (using `\scshape`). I'm not aware of an all-caps macro that doesn't take an argument (which doesn't mean there isn't one `:-)`), and I also suspect that `\uppercase` is incompatible to `hyperref`'s machinations in a more basic way. (TeX gurus, please coment on this!)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\scshape}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendixpage}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapterfont}{}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\appendix \appendixpage

\chapter{Alpha}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's close, but I'll have to fight with my graduate school to get small caps accepted. I've had another idea to try and patch the `\@chapter` command to insert the one extra command I needed, but that's failing for me as well. Editing my original question to add that, or if it's a better idea to make a second question, I can do that, too.

Comment: Any updates on this answer? I'm in the same boat but would like to avoid Small Caps.