# Hyperref breaks my all-caps ToC entries

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents, memoir, etoolbox

I started out on [this earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11691/making-memoir-chapter-entries-in-toc-all-caps-and-appendix-entries-regular-case). I now have a simple and elegant `etoolbox` solution to making all-caps chapter entries, but leaving appendix entries untouched. Simple, elegant, and incompatible with `hyperref`, it seems.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ifpatchable*{\@chapter}{\typeout{Chapter can be patched}}{\typeout{Chapter cannot be patched}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc \def\f@rtoc{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\typeout{Succeeded}}%
{\typeout{Failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\appendix \appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\end{document}
```

which indicates that the `\@chapter` command can be patched, my patch succeeds, and I get the PDF output I wanted:

[image: ToC with all-caps chapters, normal appendices, and no hyperrefs]

Enabling the `hyperref` package reverts my changes to the ToC format, somehow:

[image: ToC with normal chapters and appendices, plus hyperrefs]

---

EDIT: After adding `\tracingpatches` to the preamble, the working version puts the following in the logs:

```
Chapter can be patched
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 8
[debug] analyzing \@chapter
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] ++ search pattern found in replacement text
[debug] ++ patching possible
[debug] == retokenizing macro now
Succeeded
```

and the failing version puts instead:

```
Chapter can be patched
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 8
[debug] analyzing \@chapter
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -- search pattern not found in replacement text
Failed
```

I don't see any obvious places where hyperref modifies `\@chapter`, but I could have certainly missed something.

---

Final Working Example (including hyperref):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\ifpatchable*{\@chapter}{\typeout{Chapter can be patched}}{\typeout{Chapter cannot be patched}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc \def\f@rtoc{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\typeout{Succeeded}}%
{\typeout{Failed}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\appendix \appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with hyperrefs, and in all caps]

Comment: Try loading hyperref _after_ all the other packages.

Comment: I'm loading it after all the other packages in the MWE.

Comment: And hyperref is redefining `\@chapter` considerably. So says `\show\@chapter` from the working version to the non-working one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load hyperref *immediately before `\begin{document}`* -- i.e., after all packages *and* after all macro redefinitions.

EDIT: This is not a general rule, only a solution for your minimal example.

Comment: And that makes my `\@chapter` patch work properly again. Thanks.