# Lowercase TOC with memoir and hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir, capitalization

When using `memoir` and `hyperref` I can't make chapters lowercase in the TOC or I get all sorts of errors.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\scshape}              % WORKS
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\scshape\MakeLowercase}  % DOESN'T WORK

\usepackage{hyperref} % Without hyperref it's all good

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents*
  \chapter{One}
  \clearpage
  \chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: `\MakeLowercase` is not expandable... so `hyperref` goes mad about this ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So what do I do, is there a way to work around that?

Comment: Well, yes and no. See p. 158 of the current `memoir` manual

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, that's great, thank you! I searched the manual a lot before asking here, but missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (p 158):

> *About upper or lower casing TOC entries*
>
> Some designs call for upper (or lower casing) TOC entries. This is possible but the solution depends on whether the [`hyperref` package](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is used or not.
>
> Without hyperref one can simply end the `\cftKfont` with say `\MakeTextUppercase` and the `K`-type entry will be upper cased.
>
> With `hyperref` the possibilities are limited. Explanation: The upper/lower casing macros are not that robust, and need the content to be simple - for some definition of simple. When `hyperref` is used, the hyperlink is wrapped around the entry before `\cftKfont` gains access to it, and is thus generally too complicated for, say, `\MakeTextUppercase` to handle. The following
>   workaround draws inspiration from [`hyperref` breaks my all-caps ToC entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11892/5764):
>
> `\settocpreprocessor{<type>}{<code>}`
>
> Here `<type>` is one of `chapter`, `part` or `book`. If needed we will attempt to add a similar feature to the rest of the sectional types, please write the maintainer. And `<code>` can be something like this:
>
> ```
> \makeatletter
> \settocpreprocessor{chapter}{%
>   \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
>   \def\f@rtoc{%
>     \texorpdfstring{\MakeTextUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}{\tempf@rtoc}}%
> }
> \makeatother
> ```
>
> Where `\f@rtoc` is a placeholder inside `\chapter`, `\part` and `\book`, holding the material to be written to the actual TOC file before `hyperref` accesses it. This way the upper casing is sneaked into the TOC file, and the bookmark part of `hyperref` will not complain about the `\MakeTextUppercase` in the data. Of course, you will not have upper cased titles in the bookmark list.

With the above in mind, you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\settocpreprocessor{chapter}{%
  \let\temp@f@rtoc\f@rtoc
  \def\f@rtoc{\texorpdfstring{\MakeTextLowercase{\temp@f@rtoc}}{\temp@f@rtoc}}
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\scshape}% Formatting the \chapter ToC entries

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First}

\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}[1]{\scshape\lowercase{#1}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents*

  \chapter{One}
  \clearpage
  \chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]