# MakeUpperCase problem in memoir headings

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I've had to concoct a pseudo-smallcapping command to cope with characters outside the norm (e.g. h-breve) and thus far have had no problems with it, in body text or in headings.

However, just today I've found that its use in `memoir` headings is very hit and miss. In the following code sequence, for example,

```
\chapter{Text Editions} % follows \appendix
<snip>
\subsubsection{The interpretation of \lgm{an} as \smn{dingir}}\label{B.3.4.1}
\subsubsection{The interpretation of similar Sumerian elements}\label{B.3.4.4}
\subsection{The name element \lgm{an-na}}\label{B.3.5}

...
```

the `\lgm{}` command which uses it (for expansion see MWE below) works fine the first time, but gives an error the second time (depending on other changes, the `hyperref` error appears or not):

[image]
Changing various parts of the file such as removing an alteration of `\settocdepth{}` or other commands which potentially affect header numbering can cause the error to vanish.

Here's a MWE which illustrates the problem, with two of the types of changes which hide it.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{memoir}

% Removing the next line avoids the error
\settocdepth{subsection}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
    \setotherlanguage[]{french}
    \setotherlanguage[spelling=old]{german}
\usepackage[%
    xetex,bookmarks,
    colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue,breaklinks=true,
    pdftitle={Karljürgen G. Feuerherm---Abum--waqar and His Circle},
    pdfauthor={Karljürgen G. Feuerherm},
    unicode
    ]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\fakesc}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{FakeStretch=1.1092,FakeBold=1.0,Scale=0.71}\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lgm}[1]{{\sffamily\fakesc{#1}}}
\newcommand{\smn}[1]{{\sffamily{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0}#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Text Editions}
% Removing the next group of lines, or changing their level, avoids the error
\section{Preliminary remarks}\label{B.1}
\section{Principles of transliteration and transcription}\label{B.2}
\subsection{Typographic representation of cuneiform signs}\label{B.2.1}
\subsection{Consonantal ‘i’}\label{B.2.2}
\subsection{\smn{sa₁₀} and \smn{šám}}\label{B.2.3}
\subsection{Superscripted sigla}\label{B.2.4}
\subsection{Damage mark-up}\label{B.2.5}
\section{Principles of translation}\label{B.3}
\subsection{General}\label{B.3.1}
\subsection{Names with exclusively Sumerian elements}\label{B.3.2}
\subsection{Names with exclusively Akkadian elements}\label{B.3.3}
\subsection{Names with both Sumerian and Akkadian elements}\label{B.3.4}
\subsubsection{The interpretation of \lgm{an} as \smn{dingir}}\label{B.3.4.1}
\subsubsection{The interpretation of similar Sumerian elements}\label{B.3.4.4}
\subsection{The name element \lgm{an-na}}\label{B.3.5}

\end{document}
```

I have a very dim recollection of having perhaps experienced something similar a few years ago but I can't put my finger on it. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396367/lowercase-toc-with-memoir-and-hyperref

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. Having read memoir p. 158, though, it seems this won't likely work for <sub>sections, and I rather need to do this as it's the convention in the field. (Ultimately I maybe can ditch hyperref if electronic publication is not possible but of course I'd rather avoid avoiding the problem....)

Comment: Maybe try `\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\texorpdfstring{xxx}{#1}}`, where `xxx` is your current definition of the command.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Not sure about that, I use `\textsc{}` elsewhere.

Comment: I've come up with a kludgy workaround that gets me by for the moment though I'm waiting for it to bite me down the road: duplicated the font and copied the uppercase glyphs into the lowercase slots, and removed the `\MakeUppercase`. But some way to patch the code would definitely be preferable.

Comment: OK - you could still try the `\texorpdfstring` fix with `\fakesc`. It seems all the error messages arise in a pdf-string context.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer It does seem to alleviate the warnings, which is something.